# locationServicesEnabled in iOS >4.0 always showing UIAlert

Tags: iphone, mapkit, cllocationmanager, locationmanager

I try do get the locationServicesEnabled function to work... but my UIAlert shows up no matter if the locationServices is enabled or not! How do I get this to work properly?

```
 @synthesize locationServicesEnabled
    -(void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
      self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
      locationManager.delegate = self;
      locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
      [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        } else {
            [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location services." 
                                         message:@"Location services are disabled." 
                                        delegate:nil 
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                               otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];       
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this a subview of some sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your condition is backwards.  It currently says "if NOT location-services-enabled then start updating else alert".

Change the `if` to:

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
```

Remove the `!`.

Comment: still doesn't work... Tried to put the alert to the if statement and the locationmanager to the else statement. I also removed the "!". It still shows an alert no matter what my settings for the location services

Comment: Are you testing with location services on or off?  The alert may not show the way you are doing it from viewDidLoad.  Show it using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: or move the code to viewDidAppear.

Comment: how do I show it using the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay?

Comment: Before you do that: What device are you testing on?  Add NSLogs in both the if and else parts to see which part is executing.

Comment: 2010-12-27 17:54:17.455 XXX[3201:307] Shows ALERT                    2010-12-27 17:54:31.011 XXX[3201:307] User location view is NOT visible but should be. Showing....

Comment: Don't worry about that message.  Put your own NSLogs in the if and else parts.  Also note that locationServicesEnabled returns the device-level setting (not the app-level setting).

Comment: Yeah. I did. The only thing that executes is the alert in the if statement

Comment: It works with my devices.  Is this the actual code?  Why do you have a locationServicesEnabled property?

Comment: I removed the property and tried again. The alert still comes up no matter what my settings are.

Comment: It's not a strict requirement.  If you don't check, the OS will automatically prompt the user whether they want to turn location services on or not.  When you build the app, do you see a compiler warning on the `if` line?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

Comment: Nope, I did first... it said locationServicesEnabled is deprecated. Now I don't see it. But if I don't have this locationServicesEnabled, can I still launch my app on the AppStore?

Comment: Yes and the doc for the new class method says the OS will prompt if you don't check.  Do you see a compiler warning on the if line?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about not checking.  But it might just be a problem with how you're doing the testing.  After you change the location services setting, terminate the app and re-start it.  Also try deleting the app from the device and starting over.

Comment: So if I don't use the locationServicesEnabled in my app, i'm not condemned by Apple?

Comment: The doc only says (1) if you are going to call locationServicesEnabled at all then use the new class method, and (2) you "should" check first.  It doesn't say you "must".  I very much doubt an app would be rejected because it doesn't check locationServicesEnabled first.  But as I said, there is something else wrong here.  It works for me.